# "Keep your pants on?" or "Hold your pants on?"

Tags: expressions

My dad used to say "Keep your pants on" but my wife insists the saying is "Hold your pants on" To me the two phrases mean two totally different things. Which one is (or was) a more common phrase?

Comment: I've never heard "Hold your pants on". It sounds awkward and unidiomatic to me. I'm a native speaker of American English (Northwest). Where is your wife from? Is English her first language? If so, what dialect does she speak? British English? Australian? American South?

Comment: Perhaps your wife is conflating (primarily AmE) *Keep your pants on* with (primarily BrE, I think) ***Hold** your horses.* But it's trivial to google the ***pants on*** version with ***keep*** and ***hold*** to see which is more common.

Comment: @FumbleFingers We Leftpodians say *hold your horses* as well. You know, we have cowboys and all.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: This [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hold+your+horses%3Aeng_us_2012%2C+hold+your+horses%3Aeng_gb_2012%2C+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chold%20your%20horses%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chold%20your%20horses%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) suggests that Yank cowboys hold horses even more than do the Brits.

Comment: @Dan: Apparently, [Hold your horses!](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Hold+your+horses&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHold%20your%20horses%3B%2Cc0) didn't really gain traction until long after cowboys and all (note the *massive* upswing since the 70s). But checking AmE/BrE corpuses on that link, it does seem to be slightly more common on your side of the pond, so my earlier guess was incorrect.

Comment: @Drew: Americans definitely say [*Hold your **water**!*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Hold+your+water&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHold%20your%20water%3B%2Cc0) more than Brits.Before I just looked it up, I'd always assumed that one implied *Have courage! (Don't piss yourself with fear),* but I see it's defined as *To be patient; to control one's impulses,* which makes it pretty much equivalent to the *horses* version I'm familiar with.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Apparently we hold more than you [in both cases](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Hold+your+water%3Aeng_us_2012%2Chold+your+horses%3A+eng_us_2012%2CHold+your+water%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Chold+your+horses%3A+eng_gb_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHold%20your%20water%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chold%20your%20horses%3A%20eng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHold%20your%20water%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chold%20your%20horses%3A%20eng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) - at least in absolute number of references.

Comment: perhaps the 'hold onto your pants' version has got confused somewhere along the way with 'hold onto your *hat*.

Comment: @Drew: We Brits are *always* "outnumbered" on NGrams, but it's interesting to note that the usage barely existed in BrE until WW2, so perhaps it gained currency from US servicemen in Europe (by which time the original *literal* sense would have had little relevance anyway).

Comment: I think that _hold your britches_ is more common than _hold your pants on_.

Comment: What meaning do you think either of these phrases has?

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with Fumble' s comment. This is likely a conflation of information your wife is performing.

Typically it's either -

Keep your pants on: means to wait patiently

or

Hold your horses: slow down, hold on, wait, be patient

or alternatively

Cool your jets: slow down, hold on